# Improve efficiency of text file processing using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I've got a text file with >1 million observations in it that I'm trying to process into a dataframe. The problem is it looks like this:

```
product/productId: blah blah
product/title: blue shirt
product/price: unknown
review/userId: blah blah
review/text: blah blah

product/productId: blah blah
product/title: pair of jeans
product/price: unknown
review/userId: blah blah
review/text: blah blah
```

Every block of text is a unique observation, and I have to group them and make them into rows in a neat dataframe. So all in all, this is over 5 million lines that need to be processed.

I'm fairly new to Python so I'm not quite sure what the best way of cleaning this up would be. I started by reading the file into a Pandas df:

```py
initialData = pd.read_csv(args["data_file"], sep="\n", header=None, dtype=str)
initialData.columns = [ "data" ]

print(initialData.head(5), "\n\n", initialData.shape)
```

Output:

```
                                                data
0                      product/productId:  blah blah
1   product/title: blah blah
2                             product/price: unknown
3                      review/userId: blah blah
4   review/profileName: blah blah

 (5819330, 1)
```

Then I try using the following function to organize the data in each line into its respective row with named columns:

```py
def organize_data(df):
    df["col"] = 0
    # group lines by observation represented
    for line_count in range(0, len(df), 10):
        indices = [ line_count, line_count + 1, line_count + 2,
                    line_count + 3, line_count + 4, line_count + 5,
                    line_count + 6, line_count + 7, line_count + 8, line_count + 9 ]
        # iterate through grouped lines
        for index in indices:
            row = df.iloc[index]
            # split inputs, assign one to "col" column
            # that'll be used to assign each value to its
            # respective column
            split_row = row["data"].split(" ", 1)
            new_label = split_row[0]
            last_split = new_label.split("/")
            future_col_name = last_split[1]
            row["col"] = future_col_name
    organized_df = df.pivot(columns="col", values="data")

    return organized_df
```

As you can imagine given that it iterates through literally every line in the file, it's unbelievably slow. And it gives me a SettingWithCopyWarning to boot, so it doesn't even do what I want it to when it's finished. How can I deal with these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some preprocessing of your data instead of using read_csv.  I'd recommend defaultdict from the collections module to group all columns in a list.  We can then pass the defaultdict into the DataFrame constructor to get the final output:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

with open('reviews.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for line in lines:
        col,value = line.split(':')
        data[col.strip()].append(value.strip())

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)

   product/productId  product/title product/price review/userId review/text
0          blah blah     blue shirt       unknown     blah blah   blah blah
1          blah blah  pair of jeans       unknown     blah blah   blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to switch to [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) or [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html).

If you want to continue using pandas, try the following tips to read a CSV file, with [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

1. `chunksize` parameter: that allows you to read a piece of files at a time. For
   example in your case you could use chunksize equal to a million, you
   would get 5 chunks and you could operate on each chunk
   individually. In this way you will use an **iterator** and `chunksize=1000000` does is to give you a reader object that *[iterates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking)* 1000000-row DataFrames instead of reading the whole thing.
   In other words, to iterate through a (potentially very large) file lazily rather than reading the entire file into memory - specify a chunksize to read_csv call (specifying a number of rows to read at one iteration)
2. `dtype` parameter: with this parameter you can specify the data type of each column simply by passing a dictionary like this: `{‘a’: np.float32, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int32’}`
   Pandas could use 64-bit data types, while 32bit might be enough for you. With this trick you could save 50% of the space.